# Partition array using index in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for an elegant way to partition an array by using index in ruby

eg:

```
["a","b",3,"c",5].partition_with_index(2) 
    => [["a","b",3],["c",5]]
```

So far the best that I can think is using the below

```
["a","b",3,"c",5].partition.each_with_index{|val,index| index <= 2}
    => [["a","b",3],["c",5]]
```

Is there any other elegant way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do:

```
["a","b",3,"c",5].partition.with_index { |_, index| index <= 2 }
```

Following @toro2k advice, I think this is a better solution because you are combining the two `Enumerators` to get the desired output.

If you don’t pass a block of code to `partition`, it returns an `Enumerator` object instead. `Enumerators` have a `with_index` method that will maintain the current loop index.

Comment: I think you should elaborate on why this is a better solution then the one proposed by OP.

Comment: @toro2k I think it's a little bit better now :)

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you use [array.slice!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice-21)

> array#slice! Deletes the element(s) given by an index (optionally up to length elements) or by a range.

```
> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 5]
> b = a.slice! 0, 2 # => ['a', 'b'] 
> a # => ['c', 5]
```

In your case,

```
> [a.slice!(0, index), a]
```

Comment: To achieve the same result as in the OP: 

`> a = ['a', 'b', 3, 'c', 5]`

`> [a.slice!(0,2), a] # => [["a", "b", 3], ["c", 5]]`

Comment: I think this is way less readable at first sight, but it's cool nonetheless

Comment: `slice` is an alias for `[]`, so why not `[a[0..2], a[3..-1]]`?.

Comment: @nicooga: reason is elegance! slice is verbose than [],  in slice all I need is to specify starting offset and the number of elements to be sliced off, but in [n..m] the index locations (start,end) needs to be provided. Also, I am using slice!, so the object gets mutated by slice operation, so instead of a[3..-1] for second element I can just use `a`. Think about an arbitrary index variable, now [a.slice!(0,index), a] and [a[0..index],a[index+1..-1]] which you think is elegant? Hope you understand my reasons.

Comment: Problem is you are modifying the receiver, what generally you don't want. However, this all is just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 6):

You could use Enumerable's `take` and `drop` methods:

```
a = ["a","b",3,"c",5]
[a.take(3), a.drop(3)]  # => [["a", "b", 3], ["c", 5]]
```

I made an [Enumerable quick reference sheet](http://www.davidegrayson.com/ruby/enumerable/enumerable_methods.pdf) you might want to consult for questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done, but not sure if it elegant or not :

```
a = ["a","b",3,"c",5]
index = 2
[a[0..index], a[index+1..-1]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case, 'pyper' gem is usable:

```
require 'pyper' # gem install pyper if necessary
include Pyper

ary = ["a", "b", 3, "c", 5]
ary.τ3τ #=> ["a", "b", 3]
ary.τfτ #=> ["c", 5]
```

It only works easily on small n (number of chopped-off elements), but `Pyper` provides many other frequently encountered tasks on collections. It was inspired by lisp's `car` and `cdr` functions ([see details by an anonymous donor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_and_cdr)), and the letters can be combined together into a control string, a bit like in APL. Greek tau (τ) is used to denote methods instead of `c` and `r`, so `car`, `cdr` become `τaτ`, `τdτ`:

```
ary.τaτ #=> "a"
ary.τdτ #=> ["b", 3, "c", 5]
# Instead of τfτ, one can write
ary.τdddτ #=> ["c", 5]
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below :

```
a = ["a","b",3,"c",5]
par = a.slice_before(sum: -2) do |elem, state|
  state[:sum] += 1
  state[:sum] == 2
end.to_a
par
# => [["a", "b", 3], ["c", 5]]
```